# Nestjs prisma global exception handler status is always 500

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, prisma

this is the **all-exception.filter.ts**:

```
@Catch()
export class AllExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor(private readonly httpAdapterHost: HttpAdapterHost) {}

  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const { httpAdapter } = this.httpAdapterHost;

    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    const message = exception.message;
    const status =
      exception instanceof HttpException
        ? exception.getStatus()
        : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    console.log();

    const responseBody = {
      success: false,
      message,
    };

    httpAdapter.reply(ctx.getResponse(), responseBody, status);
  }
}
```

and this is a service method that returning just one item:

```
  findOne(id: number) {
    return this.prisma.restaurant.findUniqueOrThrow({
      where: {
        id,
      },
    });
  }
```

The problem is that **findUniqueOrThrow** will throw 404 if the item is not found. but in the global filter when I log the status, I always receive a 500 status code.

Answer (score 1):

Here a full example for filter handling  when Prisma.findFirstOrThrow  throw not found exception:

notFound.filter.ts

```
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, ExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NotFoundError } from '@prisma/client/runtime';
import { Response } from 'express';

@Catch(NotFoundError)
export class NotFoundExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  public catch(exception: NotFoundError, host: ArgumentsHost) {

    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    return response.status(404).json({ statusCode: 404, error: 'Not Found' });
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  ...
  app.useGlobalFilters(new NotFoundExceptionFilter());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

Et voila !

Comment: NotFoundError is being depreceated

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to segregate the **HttpExceptionFilter** and **AllExceptionFilter**.

```ts
@Catch()
export class AllExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    console.log(exception);

    response
      .status(status)
      .json(ResultFactory.getFailureResult(exception.message));
  }
}
```

```ts
@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const status = exception.getStatus();

    console.log(exception);

    response
      .status(status)
      .json(ResultFactory.getFailureResult(exception.message));
  }
}
```

Then, apply the AllExceptionFilter to global filter:

```ts
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  // Filters
  app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter());
  
  ...

  await app.listen(PORT);
}
bootstrap();
```

And apply the HttpExceptionFilter to Controller class you using. Then that might have the higher priority than `AllExceptionFilter`. So, httpExceptions caused by Prisma be filtered by `HttpExceptionFilter`, and only `uncaughtException` be filtered by `AllExceptionFilter`.

Below code snippet is example for above:

```ts
@ApiTags('인증/인가')
@Controller('api/users')
@UseFilters(HttpExceptionFilter)
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}
  
  @Post('/sign-up')
  async signup(@Body() createRequest: CreateUserRequest) {
    return await this.usersService.signup(createRequest);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`prisma` on it's own does not throw an `HttpException` from Nest, which is where the `getStatus()` method exists. The error thrown will also fail the `exception instanceof HttpException` check. You should wrap the call in a `try/catch` and transform the error to the appropriate exception type so that Nest's filter can handle sending back to proper exception status code

Comment: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#finduniqueorthrow
Do you mean this doesn't return a 404 error? I want to not repeat the try-catch for 404 error

Comment: You can create your own filter then that knows how to handle prisma errors rather than `HttpException` instances. But Nest, by default, will not understand that `NotFoundError` should return a 404, and this is mainly due to JS not having a standard Error library other than just the `Error` class

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this problem before. I think you are using `app.useGlobalFilters` method. Try using this instead:

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { APP_FILTER } from "@nestjs/common";

@Module(
 providers: [
   {
     provide: APP_FILTER,
     useClass: AllExceptionsFilter,
   }
 ]
)
```

This solved my issue.